# What is the idea behind of the RFC ERROR?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I'm trying to understand the idea of `RFC ERROR`, it looks to consist of an `RFC Code`, `RFC Text`.

I want to know:

- What does the `RFC` stand for in such context?
- Why do we have to define and use such errors?

Comment: Hey @JinLing we need more context. RFC can be "Request For Comments", in this scenario, there is one RFC that has the goal of standardizing the error messages of HTTP APIs. Here is the link:https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807 Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: @ViniciusScheidegger thank you so much, this is really what I want. Actually, I don't know what `RFC` stands for in the problem's context, I just know the name. But you really get the point and help me figure out the idea behind it.